# Encrypting A Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, passwords, protected

I am trying to create a web page that a password needs to be entered to access the content on the page, and I want to make sure that the password can not easily be found in view source or in any other files referenced in the file.

I have found a few things online, but I can not figure out how to use a password that can not be easily viewed. I am hosting the website myself, so I have access to whatever I need to do.

Hopefully someone can give me an idea,
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need server-side code (like PHP). Can't effectively be done client-side (i.e. just HTML/CSS/JavaScript).

Comment: This is where a backend such as PHP comes in handy. Frontend JavaScript sends it via POST to the backend (PHP), the backend "replies" OK or FAIL and there you go, the users using the front end can't see the password. Crude answer.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the web server running?  If it is Apache then you can easily do this using a .htaccess file with something like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/password/file
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
Require valid-user
```

If you are on an IIS server then you will need to go something like:

https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: I am currently running Windows 10, and I am using WAMP.